# Need Help joining a key between three tables

Tags: sql

OK, I am having difficulties with this query, What I want to do is join titles.pub_id to publishers.pub_id and then join publishers.pub_id onto employee.pub_id.

This is what I have came up with so far

In the titles table
`title_id` is the primary key
`pub_id` is a foreign key

In the publishers table
`pub_id` is the primary key
`pub_name` is a canidate key

in the employee table `pub_id` is a foreign key

```
SELECT titles.title_id
FROM titles
INNER JOIN titleauthor on titleauthor.title_id = titles.title_id
--INNER JOIN employee on employee.pub_id = publishers.pub_id
--INNER JOIN publishers on publishers.pub_id = titles.pub_id
```

The error that I get from this query is

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "publishers.pub_id" could not be bound.
```

Comment: What's stopping you?  What error messages are you getting?  Are you getting any unexpected output?  What about the `titleauthor` table?

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "publishers.pub_id" could not be bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joins are left-associative, so an `ON` clause can only refer to tables that are joined earlier in the query, not to tables that are joined later. So you need to change the order of these two lines:

```
INNER JOIN employee on employee.pub_id = publishers.pub_id
INNER JOIN publishers on publishers.pub_id = titles.pub_id
```

giving this:

```
INNER JOIN publishers on publishers.pub_id = titles.pub_id
INNER JOIN employee on employee.pub_id = publishers.pub_id
```

in order that `on employee.pub_id = publishers.pub_id` not refer to `publishers` before it's joined.

Comment: "Joins are left-associative" -- this only applies to the `ON` syntax from a parsing point of view. If you simplify using `NATURAL [INNER] JOIN` then the joins will be associative as regards parsing.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Well, no, it also affects actual join semantics in some cases. For example, `t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON 1=1 INNER JOIN t3 ON 2=2` means `(t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON 1=1) INNER JOIN t3 ON 2=2`, *not* `t1 LEFT JOIN (t2 INNER JOIN t3 ON 2=2) ON 1=1`, so it doesn't necessarily return a result for every record in `t1`.

Comment: I thought it was implicit this discussion was limited to inner joins; agreed that outer join is not associative. In terms of relational operators, inner join is associative; think of it as a 'feature' of SQL Server** that if you change the order of inner joins in the `FROM` clause then you may have to change the `ON` clauses. ** I say this because the OP's uncommented query is valid standard SQL according to the [Mimer SQL:1992 validator](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser92/index.tml).

Comment: @onedaywhen: Understood. The reason I wrote "joins are left-associative" instead of "*inner* joins are left-associative" or "*your* joins are left-associative" or whatnot is that I intended it as a general statement about joins. But I see how that might not have come through.

Comment: (Tongue in cheek) oh you mean a general rule that only applies to SQL Sever, and only to certain join types, and only in certain circumstances (such as when joins to the right are not enclosed in parentheses)? Seriously, I think we've cleared things up, thanks :)

Comment: @onedaywhen: In principle, yes. But instead of "only applies to SQL Sever [sic]", it's "only applies to the SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and probably other DMBSes"; instead of "only to certain join types" it's "to all join types"; and instead of "only in certain circumstances" it's "in all circumstances". (Unless you want to argue that `/` is left-associative "only in certain circumstances" on the grounds that `a/(b/c)` performs `b/c` first?)

Comment: @onedaywhen: By the way, that Mimer SQL:1992 validator doesn't report any error even if the `ON` clause refers to tables that aren't joined at *all*, *anywhere* in the query; so it doesn't support your claim.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT title_id
FROM (
  (
    titles LEFT JOIN titleauthor USING(title_id)
  ) LEFT JOIN publishers USING(pub_id)
) LEFT JOIN employee USING(pub_id)
```

*Note*: It seems to me that what you need to obtain from this query can be achieved by using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN (querying faster, consume less memory)

Comment: can you cite any credible sources that back up your claim that `LEFT JOIN`s are faster and consume less memory? (remember this question is not RDBMS specific too) `LEFT JOIN` should be used if it makes sense to do so depending on the needs

Comment: In fact, I fail to see how a `left join` could consume less memory than an `inner join`, since the result set of the former contains at least as many rows and columns as the latter.

Comment: I were NOT said that LEFT JOIN is faster/consume less memory in GENERAL, I'm saying that it SEEMS for Steffan's query (case specific).

In many ways, INNER JOIN can give faster result by nature of it;s optimization. But there are also cases where outer join (LEFT / RIGHT join) is more beneficial / preferreble, and it seems Steffan's case is one of the latter.

It's not about which one is better, it's really depend on situation.

Comment: Steffan has just given a simplified version of his query to make his question clear, but it seems (I'm guessing), he try to show list of publication with corresponding detailed information. In this case, the loop required is from left-most table parsed to right-most table, no records exclusion needed, therefore LEFT JOIN will be perfectly suitable for this kind of query.

In case of filtering is based on various field across tables, INNER JOIN will perform much better as heavy conditional checks will be performed in already-compacted set of records.

Comment: @Jack: What I mean with 'less memory' is not memory in client side (for holding fetched rows), but memory in server used to process the query. In general SQL engine implementation, inner join creates a new temporary array (index of indexes) when evaluating data from multiple table as part of it's record exclusion process. In other hand, LEFT JOIN simply iterate records over indexes (given the join key is indexed in both tables).